# scsi slide-scanner is visible to scanimage -L once, then disappears

Tags: canon, scanner, udev, sane, scsi

We have a slide-scanner from the early 2000s. It is recognized by the PC, but only once. There seems to be a tiny error in some config file (/etc/sane.d/, or in /etc/udev/rules.d), but we cannot figure it out what's wrong or missing.

The output below indicates that there is a `hardware error` and a `lamp failure`, but this is most likely misleading. The scanner works properly  when booted with an old Windows XP PC which runs the proprietary Canon Software. Scanning works under Windows, the lamp is old but okay. Moreover, the scanner *has* worked on this Linux PC (only the hard drive was changed) for a very brief time, and then stopped  working, apparently after the first run of `apt upgrade`.

[image: screenshot sdiff output]

Command:

```
    export SANE_DEBUG_CANON=255 && export SANE_DEBUG_SANEI_SCSI=255 && export SANE_DEBUG_DLL=255  && scanimage -L
```

Output first time:

```
device `canon:/dev/sg2' is a CANON IX-27015C        film scanner
```

Output:

```
[sanei_debug] Setting debug level of canon to 255.
[canon] >> sane_init
[canon] sane_init: sane-backends 1.0.25git
[canon] >> attach_one
[canon] >> attach
[canon] attach: opening /dev/sg1
[canon] attach: open failed: Invalid argument
[canon] << attach_one
[canon] >> attach_one
[canon] >> attach
[canon] attach: opening /dev/sg2
[canon] attach: sending (standard) INQUIRY
[canon] >> inquiry
[canon] << inquiry
[canon] attach: sending TEST_UNIT_READY
[canon] >> test_unit_ready
[canon] >> sense_handler
[canon] canon_sense_handler(10, 0xb6bf1060, (nil))
[canon] sense buffer: f0 00 44 00 00 00 00 06 00 00 00 00 60 00 00 00
[canon] sense data interpretation for SCSI-2 devices
[canon] sense category: hardware error
[canon] sense message: lamp failure
[canon] << sense_handler
[canon] << test_unit_ready
[canon] attach: test unit ready failed (Error during device I/O)
[canon] << attach_one
[canon] << sane_init
[canon] >> sane_get_devices
[canon] << sane_get_devices

No scanners were identified. If you were expecting something different,
check that the scanner is plugged in, turned on and detected by the
sane-find-scanner tool (if appropriate). Please read the documentation
which came with this software (README, FAQ, manpages).
[canon] >> sane_exit
[canon] << sane_exit
```

The output that `scanimage -L` generates looks similar to this:

Scanning for device 4 0 3 0 ...

```
OLD: Host: scsi4 Channel: 00 Id: 03 Lun: 00
      Vendor: CANON    Model: IX-27015C        Rev: 1.15
      Type:   Scanner                          ANSI SCSI revision: 02
```

udevadm command:

```
 udevadm info -a -p /sys/class/scsi_generic/sg2
```

udevadm output:

```
Udevadm info starts with the device specified by the devpath and then
walks up the chain of parent devices. It prints for every device
found, all possible attributes in the udev rules key format.
A rule to match, can be composed by the attributes of the device
and the attributes from one single parent device.

  looking at device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1e.0/0000:05:05.0/host4/target4:0:3/4:0:3:0/scsi_generic/sg2':
    KERNEL=="sg2"
    SUBSYSTEM=="scsi_generic"
    DRIVER==""

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1e.0/0000:05:05.0/host4/target4:0:3/4:0:3:0':
    KERNELS=="4:0:3:0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="scsi"
    DRIVERS==""
    ATTRS{device_blocked}=="0"
    ATTRS{device_busy}=="0"
    ATTRS{dh_state}=="detached"
    ATTRS{eh_timeout}=="10"
    ATTRS{evt_capacity_change_reported}=="0"
    ATTRS{evt_inquiry_change_reported}=="0"
    ATTRS{evt_lun_change_reported}=="0"
    ATTRS{evt_media_change}=="0"
    ATTRS{evt_mode_parameter_change_reported}=="0"
    ATTRS{evt_soft_threshold_reached}=="0"
    ATTRS{iocounterbits}=="32"
    ATTRS{iodone_cnt}=="0x19"
    ATTRS{ioerr_cnt}=="0x6"
    ATTRS{iorequest_cnt}=="0x19"
    ATTRS{model}=="IX-27015C       "
    ATTRS{queue_depth}=="2"
    ATTRS{queue_type}=="none"
    ATTRS{rev}=="1.15"
    ATTRS{scsi_level}=="3"
    ATTRS{state}=="running"
    ATTRS{timeout}=="0"
    ATTRS{type}=="6"
    ATTRS{vendor}=="CANON   "

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1e.0/0000:05:05.0/host4/target4:0:3':
    KERNELS=="target4:0:3"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="scsi"
    DRIVERS==""

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1e.0/0000:05:05.0/host4':
    KERNELS=="host4"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="scsi"
    DRIVERS==""
```

PC data:

OS version: `4.10.0-20-generic #22-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 20 09:22:16 UTC 2017 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux`

Created by us:

contents from `/etc/udev/rules.d/45-scsi-scanner.rules` (one line:

```
# canon CanoScan 2700F scsi scanner
SUBSYSTEM=="scsi_generic", ATTRS{vendor}=="CANON", ATTRS{model}=="IX-27015C", NAME="%k", SYMLINK="scanner%n", MODE="0660",GROUP="scanner"
```

Contents of `/etc/sane.d/canon.conf`

```
#canon.conf
scsi CANON
#scsi CANON IX
#scsi /dev/sg2
```

See also this [installation instruction from 1999](https://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/sane/sane-backends.git/diff/doc/canon/canon.install2700F.txt?id=28345d62ab138444fe7fa619d52514f6cd0eb448).

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question:

Unexpectedly, the scanner revealed what's wrong after drives were changed, after accessing it again from Windows XP.

Another error message (which cannot be reproduced here - previously and afterwards unseen) indicated that the self-test at startup failed to finish.

The slider mechanism had an electronic and/or mechanical defect that prevented the scanner from working properly. Just removing the slider from the entry system made the scanner boot.